# Найти минимальное число в СИ

Tags: c

Условие задачи: в начале мы задаем "кол-во чисел последовательности", а потом вводим столько чисел ск-ко указали в числе последовательности и программа должна найти средне-арифметическое введенных чисел, минимальное и максимальное.
Проблема лишь в том, что я никак не могу найти минимальное число, а все остальное у меня получилось...Вот мой код...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    float num, sredArif = 0, maxNum = 0, minNum = 0, summa = 0;
    int count = 1, quan; // quan == quantity

    printf("Введите кол-во чисел последовательности: "); scanf_s("%d", &quan);
    printf("-> "); scanf_s("%f", &num);
    minNum = num;
    while (count <= quan - 1)
    {
        printf("-> "); scanf_s("%f", &num);
        maxNum = num;
        if (maxNum > minNum)
        {
            if (maxNum < minNum)
            {
                minNum = maxNum;
            }
        }
        summa = summa + num;
        sredArif = summa / count;
        count++;
    }
    printf("\nКол-во чисел: %d", quan);
    printf("\nСреднее арифметическое: %.2f", sredArif);
    printf("\nМаксимальное число: %.2f", maxNum);
    printf("\nМинимальное число: %.2f", minNum);

    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На оба условия в if-ах посмотри. Не вызывает вопросов?

Comment: "все остальное у меня получилось" - этот код ничего не делает правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    float num, sredArif = 0, maxNum = 0, minNum = 0, summa;
    int quan; // quan == quantity

    printf("Введите кол-во чисел последовательности: ");
    scanf("%d", &quan);
    printf("-> "); scanf("%f", &num);
    minNum = num, maxNum = num, summa = num;
    for(int i = quan; i > 1; --i)
    {
        printf("-> "); scanf("%f", &num);
        if (num < minNum)
            minNum = num;
        if (num > maxNum)
            maxNum = num;
        summa += num;
    }
    sredArif = summa / quan;

    printf("\nКол-во чисел: %d", quan);
    printf("\nСреднее арифметическое: %.2f", sredArif);
    printf("\nМаксимальное число: %.2f", maxNum);
    printf("\nМинимальное число: %.2f", minNum);

    return 0;
}
```